# Instancia local do SQL Server 2012 desapareceu

Tags: sql-server-2012

Instalei o SQL Server 2012 com o SQL Server Manager pra interagir com o banco de dados.

Fiz um logon localmente, vi o db `master`. Desconectei (não lembro se reiniciei a maquina) mas fui entrar de novo esta dando esse erro. Alguém sabe como resolvo?

> Não é possível conectar-se a MATRIX\SQLSERVER.
>
> INFORMAÇÕES ADICIONAIS:
>
> Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o
> SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível.
> Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está
> configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network
> Interfaces, error: 26 - Erro ao Localizar Servidor/Instância
> Especificada) (Microsoft SQL Server, Erro: -1)
>
> Para obter ajuda, clique em: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

Comment: O serviço está rodando?

Comment: tento logar nos servidor, na combo pra escolher o servidores e logar vou no browser for more(ele nao aparece aqui) ae tem janela 
database Engine-> 
expando ela->
ae dentro tem desenho de servidorzinho
com nome -> MINHAMAQUINA\SQLEXPRESS

Quando clico da o erro acima

como faco pra ver se esta rodando o servico?

Comment: Verifique no SQL Server Configuration Manager. É um ícone de uma maletinha vermelha que deve estar no seu menu iniciar.

Answer (score -1):

Encontrei o mesmo problema no SQL Server 2019.
A forma como resolvi o problema foi no nome do servidor, colocar apenas o nome do computador. No seu caso seria apenas:
**Nome do servidor:** MATRIX